# How can I use microseconds in ChartJs?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, momentjs

I'm using chartJs to display a large amount of data, in their docs i found they only got down to milliseconds but i need microseconds. is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use ChartJs's time unit option the answer is no, up to milliseconds are supported. [Here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#time-units) doc's reference.

As a workaround, you could set x axis as `type: linear;` and just use the raw microseconds in ChartJs's data.

Comment: thanks for the idea but i will try something close to this on Highcharts because I read that chartJs is not good with large amount of data

Comment: I don't have a huge amount of data (couple of MB) and I'm using [recharts](https://recharts.org/en-US/guide/getting-started). It's quite basic but works well.

Answer (score 0):

I already tried [Highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/index) it's pretty good with large amounts of data, but I added microseconds manually using the formatter callback function like in the example below in xAxis labels.

```
            xAxis: {
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
   return Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S.%L', your_date) + your_micro_3_digits;
                }
            }
        }
```

The downside I'm having now is that highcharts is no longer treating the labels as dates but as strings if that's okay with you.